# Details not showing with grpouping in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

i'm working on some reports of cheques.

### **This is how it appers:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

I did many grouping configurations in BIDS, but i was not able to achieve this.
Do you know how to handle this?

Stock StartNo. is row group, Cheque's status is Columng Group.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In Design view, delete the details row for column group "Used" and move the Fileds!used.value in the details row on "Torned" group. Same for "Not Used" group.